# Импорт диапазона данных листа файлов гугл шит по ID диска с помощью appscript

Tags: java, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Есть скрипт, который  должен импортировать заданный диапазон с листов таблиц которые находятся  на гугл диске, по ID гугл диска, но почему то он импортирует данные только 5 таблиц ,а на диске их 20

```
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("17Ux9i0mK_RTuLbrjFrZDGoNl3AkcEdRS").getFiles();
 

 
 while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
   var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Лист1")
   copySheet.getRange('A2:Z').clear
   var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId())
   var sheets = ss1.getSheetByName("Billing)
   var sheetsRange = sheets.getDataRange()
   var sheetsValues = sheetsRange.getValues()
  
 let pasteRow = 1

   sheetsValues.splice(0, 5)
   copySheet.getRange(pasteRow+1, 1, sheetsValues.length, sheetsValues[0].length).setValues(sheetsValues)
   pasteRow += sheetsValues.length
 Logger.log(file.getName())

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
function run() {
  const ids = folderTree();
  var copySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Лист1");
  copySheet.getRange("A2:Z").clear();
  let pasteRow = copySheet.getLastRow();
  if (ids) {
    for (i = 0; i < id.length; ++i) {
      const values = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id[i])
        .getSheetByName("Billing")
        .getDataRange()
        .getValues()
        .splice(0, 5);

      copySheet
        .getRange(pasteRow + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length)
        .setValues(values);
      pasteRow += values.length;
    }
  }
}

function folderTree(TARGET_FOLDER_ID = "17Ux9i0mK_RTuLbrjFrZDGoNl3AkcEdRS") {
  // содержимое папки
  try {
    const files =
      DriveApp.getFolderById(TARGET_FOLDER_ID).searchFiles(
        'title != "nothing"'
      );
    let booksIds = [];
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      let xFile = files.next();
      console.log("name >>>", xFile.getName(), "id >>>", xFile.getId());
      booksIds.push(xFile.getId());
    }
    return booksIds;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.stack);
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо отрабатывает все 20 книг, но почему то подтягивает с каждой книги только по 5 строк, а надо что бы тянуло всю инф с 5 стройки и дальше вниз

Comment: Все проблему исправила теперь тянет все как надо, спасибо!